# Perl Case statement for a range of dates

Tags: perl, switch-statement, case, control-structure

I have this PERL Switch..case statement:

```
switch ($today)
{ 
    case "14-Aug-2012"  { do A }
    case "15-Aug-2012"  { do B }
}#end switch
```

My problem is that the "do B" statement is the same for 15-Aug-2012 to like 01-Oct-2012. How do I say case between these dates so I don't have to rewrite the same thing for different days and making my script long?

I've put in the whole script so someone could help me use what I have to manage my question.

```
use Date::Calc
use Switch

#connect to database...

my @date_today=Today();
my $today=substr(Date_to_Text(@date_today),4,11);

Switch($today)
{
  case "14-Aug-2012" {Do A}
  case "15-Aug-2012" {Do B}
  case ...
  case ...
  case ...
}
```

The last 3 case statements are supposed to do:

```
  between 16-Aug-2012 and 28-Sep-2012 {do C}
  between 29-Sep-2012 and 26-Oct-2012 {do D}
  between 27-Oct-2012 and 09-Nov-2012 {do E}
```

Comment: The language is called Perl or perl ... not PERL.

Comment: @dgw - actually, the language is only called "**Perl**". "perl" is the name of the interpreter executable, not the language :)

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm using Date::Calc package. Let me put up the first part...                                                             Date::Calc

Comment: Please don't post code that won't compile

Answer (score 2):

Use a software engineering approach.

If you need to do the same thing for an entire range of days, use that range's ID as an discreet value to choose on. Then have a subroutine to tell you what the range ID is that the date falls on:

```
sub range_for_date {
    my $date = shift;
    # Compute the range value in some discreet subset
    # How to compute it is somewhat irrelevant
    #      and can be asked separately if you have no idea
    # discreet subset can be an index 1..N, ecpoch timestamps,
    # or a somehow-encoded range end date (e.g. "20121001" is easy)
    # For the switch example below we will assume end dates

    return $range_id; # in "20121001" format 
}

switch (range_for_date($today)) {
    case "20121001" { do B; }
    case "20120110" { do A; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNIX timestamps instead of date strings. Timestamps are integers and can easily be classified into date ranges (and reformatted using `localtime()`).

For example, use `Time::Local` and its `timelocal()` function to turn your string into a timestamp:

```
use Time::Local;
my %months = ( # necessary because timelocal() expects month numbers, not strings
  'Jan' => 0,
  'Feb' => 1,
  'Mar' => 2,
  'Apr' => 3,
  'May' => 4,
  'Jun' => 5,
  'Jul' => 6,
  'Aug' => 7,
  'Sep' => 8,
  'Oct' => 9,
  'Nov' => 10,
  'Dec' => 11
);
my $today = '15-Aug-2012';
my @t = $today =~ /(\d{4})-(\w{3})-(\d{4})/;
$t[1] = $months{$t[1]};  # turn string into integer
my $timestamp = timelocal(0, 0, 0, @t[0, 1, 2]); # sec, min, hr, day, month, year
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it that may be a bit simpler.  It simply converts the dates into YYYYMMDD format, which allows them to be sorted/compared numerically.

```
sub sortable_date
{
    my %months;
    @months{
        'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'
    } = ('01'..'12');

    if (shift() =~ /^(\d{1,2})-(\w{3})-(\d{4})/ and exists $months{$2})
    {
        return "$3$months{$2}$1";   
    }
    else { die "invalid date format!"; }
}

switch (sortable_date($today))
{ 
    case sortable_date("14-Aug-2012")                  { do A }
    case ($_[0] >= sortable_date("15-Aug-2012") and
          $_[0] <= sortable_date("01-Oct-2012"))       { do B }
}
```

I would recommend mpe's approach if you are going to be doing a lot with dates in general, though.